# BroadcastReceiver active Observable vs single check up every 10min

Tags: android, firebase, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to set up a notification service for my application that shows upcoming shifts for an employee in a workplace - when a new shift is added for an employee by his/her boss I want notification to pop up.

Now the question I have is what is the correct way to implement it. In my BroadcastReceiver should I just make an Observable that listens to the changes of a node in firestore constantly or I should not use any listeners and use jobscheduler and check every e.g 10min if any changes occured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate way to implement this would be using PUSH firebase service. Then register for PUSH on application startup, and save your token to your backend that stores the shift information.

You will likely have an API that changes, adds, or removes shifts, that API should then use the appropriate PUSH token for all employees affected by the shift change and send a payload to the appropriate devices to do a refresh or show a notification icon to open, or whatever action you want to occur from this.

Polling is not a good option, that should be a last resort and a darn good reason to do it should be supplied as it is wasteful on battery and resources.

Comment: sorry for follow up question but have been reading FCM documentation this last hour and one thing is still a bit unclear to me: "registration token" - I know that I can get it on my android device by calling FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().token but I can not find a way to get it in my admin API. I thought I could call something like "admin.auth().getUSer(''userID)...getRegistrationToken but there is no sucha thing should I get Rtoken in my android device when launching application & then save registrationToken to my Firestore  and retrive it from there in my API?:S:S

Comment: Hi pb4now. I hate to say it, but if you have never done PUSH notifications, you are in for a bit of a learning curve. It's not bad once you have done it, but first try is a bear. You use the firebase plugin to set your app up. You have to go to the portal to make an app for your push usage. You have to create your services, callbacks, and broadcast receivers. Then on startup you call the firebase to get token, and if it's null, then it is async going to retrieve it and will call onTokenUpdated to which you will need to send to your API servers to keep it current. Then your server uses it

Comment: yeap it's a bit pain in the ass but I'm not giving up:)  - but once again ty for getting me on the right track (Y)